# Pandas -- resolving row merge conflicts by selecting shorter text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns: String ID (not unique), String text.

I want to build a dataframe with two columns: String ID (unique), String text.
To make my IDs unique, I need to merge all rows with matching IDs.
However, the rows with identical IDs all have different text contents.
When merging, I want the row with the shortest text content to take precedence.

How can this be done?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own aggregation function, see more [here](https://medium.com/escaletechblog/writing-custom-aggregation-functions-with-pandas-96f5268a8596) -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'text': ['ab', 'a', 'b', 'aa']})

def shortest_agg(s):
    lst =  s.tolist()
    return sorted(lst, key = lambda x: len(x))[0]


df.groupby('id').agg(shortest_agg)

#result 
text
id
1     b
2     a
```